# Responsive Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, responsive

I'm trying to get my piechart to behave differently dependant on the view size. However the responsive obj doesn't seem to be working.

I'm trying to change the position the legend and the margin for small and large screens.

If i define the margin and legend outside of the `responsive: {}` object it works, but obviously doesnt update on small screens. But when i move it into the `responsive: {}` object it doesn't behave how i want it to any more?

I'm not sure what im doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You can find a jsfiddle version of my chart here:
https://jsfiddle.net/xqgw85mk/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small typo mistake in your code:

```
      {
        condtion: {
        minWidth: 1001
      },
      chartOptions: {
         ...
      }
    }
```

in condtion :)

Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5f7yh3L1/

---

EDIT

The margin option should be defined in the `chart` object:

```
{
condition: {
    minWidth: 1001
  },
  chartOptions: {
     chart: {
       margin: [...]
     }
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aco2sn7r/